# Google app engine website page structure

Tags: google-app-engine, web

I made a website using Google app engine however, if I want to link from the main page to a different page in the folder structure, is does not load on the website.

The links are fine, they work if I check it on a browser directly from my drive. Do I need to put the entire folder in a seperate folder somewhere for app engine to access it or does it need to be in one single, messy file?

Comment: Provide more info.. what language you are using? the config files? what do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the app.yaml file, you have to edit it and add the folders.
Ex:

```
application: xxxx
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: resources/stylesheets

- url: /imgs
  static_dir: resources/imgs

- url: /js
  static_dir: resources/js

- url: /html
  static_dir: resources/html
  mime_type: text/html

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Do I have to do that for every file or just the folders?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all your files that you want to display directly through an HTTP call in WEB-INF folder, assuming that you are coding in Java.

Comment: Eh... Basically what I have now is a folder with html css and javascript files. the main html page is liked to the application in google app engine which runs a php file, linking to the main html page.

Comment: PHP is not supported directly by App Engine, please refer to the documentation https://developers.google.com/appengine/ You can code in Java, Go and Python

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was working with Python, not Java. I got my answer from the reply above, thanks anyway for the quick reply!